# cannot print the array passed from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript

here is the code.......here i am passing a javascript array to php... something is going wrong........

html:

```
    <html>
    <body onload="aa()" >
<script language="javascript">
function aa()
{
var a, s;
a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three'];
s = JSON.stringify( a );
document.getElementById("fb_user").innerHTML= s;
}

    </script>
<form action="check1.php" method="post">
    <label id="fb_user"> </label>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
<?php

$fb_usr_id =json_decode(  $_POST['fb_user'], true );

    echo $fb_usr_id;
    ?>
```

when $fb_usr_id is echoed nothing is printed??

Comment: You are adding the JSON string to the label, instead of the input element.

Comment: @Pekka what u say pekka. cannot understand.....?

Comment: The code you have provided just creates a form it does not SUBMIT that form.  Are you SUBMITting it manually?

Comment: @James it submits the form.. why u say it is not submitting the form

Comment: Your code does this- create a form, populate the form with some stuff.  It is up to the user to click the submit button.  Is that correct?

Comment: @james ya when user click submit button the form is submitted

Answer (score 2):

Contents of **label** tags are not submitted.

Try changing 
`<label id="fb_user"> </label>` to 
`<input type="hidden" name="fb_user" id="fb_user">`

Comment: also change `document.getElementById("fb_user").innerHTML= s;` with `document.getElementById("fb_user").value= s;`

Comment: @venimus Absolutely not, the JavaScript function is called by `onload`.

Comment: Guess I should have mentioned the JS change.  Anyway, use Firebug or equivalent tool to ensure the contents of the hidden field are being updated correctly before form submission.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
    <body onload="aa()" >
<script language="javascript">
function aa()
{
var a, s;
a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three'];
s = JSON.stringify( a );
document.getElementById("fb_user").value = s;
}

    </script>
<form action="check1.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="fb_user" id = "fb_user" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On the backend do this first to check the validity of the posted variable as being json

```
var_dump( $_POST );
```

Comment: when i put var_dump( $_POST ); in php file. i get :      array(0) { }

Comment: make sure that the var_dump() I mentioned is on the page check1.php. As as sanity check, put the word "test" as the value in the hidden field temporarily then you will have identified if it is a PHP or JS problem... and as others have pointed out you need to press the submit button manually before this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of labels are not posted to the server. Instead, use `<input type="hidden">` for inputs not intended to be editable by users:

```
<input name="fb_user" id="fb_user" type="hidden" />
```

Also, you should not change the innerHTML if you just want set the value of an input element. Instead, assign the aptly named [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#dom-output-value) property.

Comment: @ask123 Can you post a complete example code or a URL to the running instance?

Comment: @ask123 Did you maybe forget to set the `name` attribute of the input element?

Comment: @ask123 You should remove the closing `</label>`. With that exact code , I get the output `Array` (php's string representation of an array).

Comment: @ask123 You may want to include `var_dump($_POST);` in your php code to catch all output.

Comment: @phihag i have remove </label> but nothing is printed??

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should do it:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="check1.php" method="post">
        <label id="fb_users_list"></label>
        <input type="hidden" name="fb_user" id="fb_user" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){
            var a, s;
            a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three'];
            s = JSON.stringify( a );
            document.getElementById("fb_users_list").innerHTML = s;
            document.getElementById("fb_user").value = s;
        })();
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please do *not* use `body onload=""`, because you open up holes to XSS attack. Just put your script below your form, or better of at the end of the body, and you won't need an `onload` event.

Comment: ya shef i had removed onload. but nothing display. any suggestion??

Comment: @ask123 did you try my code above? Is it displaying anything at all before you submit, or not?

Comment: when i click submit button .the php check1.php executes and displays :          Array . what does this mean

Comment: @ask123: Do you need to have the fb user ids in an array, or you can have them in a list as well? I mean can you change this `a = [ 'one', 'two', 'three'];` to this `a = 'one, two, three';`?